# Preg_replace with array replacements

Tags: php, regex, string

```
$string = ":abc and :def have apples.";
$replacements = array('Mary', 'Jane');
```

should become:

```
Mary and Jane have apples.
```

Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
preg_match_all('/:(\w+)/', $string, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $index => $match)
   $string = str_replace($match, $replacements[$index], $string);
```

Can I do this in a single run, using something like preg_replace?

Comment: [This](http://codepad.org/KfP3g02m) is how you can do it with an associative array.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace_callback` with a callback that consumes your replacements one after the other:

```
$string = ":abc and :def have apples.";
$replacements = array('Mary', 'Jane');
echo preg_replace_callback('/:\w+/', function($matches) use (&$replacements) {
    return array_shift($replacements);
}, $string);
```

Output:

```
Mary and Jane have apples.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
$string = ":abc and :def have apples.";
$replacements = array('Mary', 'Jane');

echo preg_replace("/:\\w+/e", 'array_shift($replacements)', $string);
```

Output:

```
Mary and Jane have apples.
```

Comment: It's not supported from PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
$to_replace = array(':abc', ':def', ':ghi');
$replace_with = array('Marry', 'Jane', 'Bob');

$string = ":abc and :def have apples, but :ghi doesn't";

$string = strtr($string, array_combine($to_replace, $replace_with));
echo $string;
```

here is result: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a4c5b00f68ec40fdb35ce189d26446e3a2501c2

Comment: This is the fastest solution because it doesn't use regex

Answer (score 3):

For a Multiple and Full array replacement by Associative Key you can use this to match your regex pattern:

```
   $words=array("_saudation_"=>"Hello", "_animal_"=>"cat", "_animal_sound_"=>"MEooow");
   $source=" _saudation_! My Animal is a _animal_ and it says _animal_sound_ ... _animal_sound_ ,  _no_match_";


  function translate_arrays($source,$words){
    return (preg_replace_callback("/\b_(\w*)_\b/u", function($match) use ($words) {    if(isset($words[$match[0]])){ return ($words[$match[0]]); }else{ return($match[0]); } },  $source));
  }


    echo translate_arrays($source,$words);
    //returns:  Hello! My Animal is a cat and it says MEooow ... MEooow ,  _no_match_
```

*Notice, thats although "_no_match_" lacks translation, it will match during regex, but 
preserve its key. And keys can repeat many times.

Comment: I recommend to add "u" modifier to the regex for supporting UTF-8 strings: `/\b_(\w*)_\b/u`. BTW, code above has a syntax error, and extra parenthesis at the end.

Comment: Looks like no extra parenthesis issue, i verified the code and is running ok. BUt i added The UTf-8. Thank you