# php shorten all urls with is.gd api in a string and linkify them

Tags: php, json, api, foreach, preg-match-all

As the title says I'm trying to shorten ***all*** urls with is.gd api in a string and linkify them.

```
function link_isgd($text)
{
    $regex = '@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-~]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $longurl)
    {
        $tiny = file_get_contents('http://isnot.gd/api.php?longurl='.$longurl.'&format=json');
        $json = json_decode($tiny, true);

        foreach($json as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($key == 'errorcode')
            {
                $link = $longurl;
            }
            else if ($key == 'shorturl')
            {
                $link = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return preg_replace($regex, '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>', $text);
}

$txt = 'Some text with links https://www.abcdefg.com/123 blah blah blah https://nooodle.com';

echo link_isgd($txt);
```

This is what I have got so far, linkifying works and so does shortening if only 1 url is in the string, however if theres 2 or more they all end up the same.

[image: if theres 2 or more they all end up the same]

**Note:** the `is.gd` was not allowed in post, SO thought I was posting a short link which is not allowed here,  so I had to change it to `isnot.gd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `$link` is not array so it takes only last assigned value of `$link`. You can replace `preg_replace` with `str_replace` and pass arrays with matches and links.

You can also use `preg_replace_callback()` and you can pass $matches directly to function which will replace with link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9416265/7082164

```
function link_isgd($text)
{
    $regex = '@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-~]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@';
    preg_match_all($regex, $text, $matches);

    $links = [];

    foreach ($matches[0] as $longurl) {
        $tiny = file_get_contents('http://isnot.gd/api.php?longurl=' . $longurl . '&format=json');
        $json = json_decode($tiny, true);

        foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'errorcode') {
                $links[] = $longurl;
            } else if ($key == 'shorturl') {
                $links[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    $links = array_map(function ($el) {
        return '<a href="' . $el . '" target="_blank">' . $el . '</a>';
    }, $links);

    return str_replace($matches[0], $links, $text);
}
```