# How to add email template this message

Tags: php, email, templates

I want to send php mail with template below is my code

```
    <?php 
    // sending email
$SendFrom = "MyWebsite <no-reply@mywebsite.com>";
$SendTo = "$user_email";
$SubjectLine = "Welcome Email Activation";

// Build Message Body from Web Form Input
$MsgBody='Hello, <br/> <br/> Your are most welcome to Mywebsite.com<br/> <br/> Before you continue kindly activate your email by clicking on the below link or copy and paste it in your browser and hit enter for your email activation to take place.<br/> <br/> <a href="'.$base_url.'activation/index.php?code='.$activation.'">'.$base_url.'activation/index.php?code='.$activation.'</a>';
$MsgBody = htmlspecialchars($MsgBody); //make content safe

// Send E-Mail and Direct Browser to Confirmation Page

mail($SendTo, $SubjectLine, $MsgBody, "From: " . $SendFrom);
    ?>
```

Notice that i using a simple php code and not PDO as it is working for me
Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: PDO? There are no database calls in your example :/

Comment: What PHP Data Objects has to do with anything here? And what is your question, exactly?

Comment: What is your question? Is the code not working?

Comment: if you want send an email with html, format the header properly if does not them message will send plain text

Comment: And do not use deprecated functions!

Comment: at:Sverri i have already database calls in my full php at:Alan and @NaijaProgrammer i just want to know how to send an email template with php, just as i described in my question as you can see how i am sending the message so i want to add an email template to the $MsgBody=

Comment: You just have to build an HTML page and load it inside a variable.

Comment: you didn't tell us what problem you're having. Given the comments and the answer below, they're pretty much correct about this.

Comment: plus, since you're trying to use `<br>`'s for line breaks, those won't work without an HTML headers declaration. If you want to use your existing code without sending as HTML, use `\n` and not `<br>`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- alright got ya on that one, yet how do i go about the HTML email template.

Comment: show us your template

Comment: @Fred-ii- i got no template design i thought there is a way of designing it in the php and send it do i have to design it in another file and include it? if so how that work?

Comment: you can easily include a file to a preset template and assigning variables to it. I can't see how that would not work, I use one myself but that template was built for a client, so I can't share it.

Comment: Here, check these out http://stackoverflow.com/q/1739188/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3706855/ they'll give you a few ideas; best I can do. Good luck - Edit: most particularly this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1739207/

Comment: @Fred-ii- @rray @alan-machado alright guys i have figure out a sending template to use but i got a problem here while i can't seems to figure out how to put the `$user_email` on the `$to` i did this `$to = '$user_email';` when it sends it fails because it is sending to `$user_email@server1.mywebsite.com` instead of `registered_user@gmail.com`

Answer (score 1):

For display html an email, you need define this info in the header, `Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8`

```
$headers = "From: no-reply@mywebsite.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

mail($SendTo, $SubjectLine, $MsgBody, $headers);
```

`mail()` function is kind painfull, there are other better options like, [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) this libs are easy to use and you don't need config headers bullshit.

Comment: OP question was about building a HTML template to his msg body.

Comment: @AlanMachado do jeito que está na pergunta, vai enviar como texto puro.

Comment: non capito ^ ^ ^ che significa?

Comment: @Fred-ii-, yo, i say the code on the question will send the email in plain text format no with html format.

Comment: *grazie mille* per la traduzione ;-)

Comment: Yeah is about building a html Template to the message body add my logos design it with a css and then add it to the php and send it.

Comment: @UchechiOdunze *"design it with a css"* - Remember to use inline CSS and not a stylesheet or `<style>` tags. Most email clients will throw those out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sometimes [SO sites](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/) gets mixed up

Comment: @AlanMachado Is there an "Italian" version? ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- dunno, check area51, i think soon will open spanish SO, in beta are [JP](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags) and [RU](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags)

Comment: thanks @rray but i still don't wanna send a plaintext either

Comment: @UchechiOdunze works? what you need?

Comment: to send mail with html template

Comment: alright guys i have figure out a sending template to use but i got a problem here while i can't seems to figure out how to put the `$user_email `on the $to i did this `$to      = '$user_email';` when it sends it fails because it is sending to `$user_email@server1.mywebsite.com` instead of `registered_user@gmail.com`

Comment: i am sending this message to the registered user and not to myself or to my host

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    function sendEmail(**$SendTo, $SubjectLine, $MsgBody,$SendFrom**)
    {

        $mail = null;
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        try
        {
            $mail->Host = "Host Name Enter"; // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            // sets the SMTP server
            $mail->Port = 2525;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username = "Enter SMTP Username"; // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password = "Enter Password";        // SMTP account password
            $mail->AddAddress($SendTo);

            $mail->SetFrom($SendFrom, 'Subject To'**);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
    //                $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('uploads/'.$res['user_img'], 'prf');
    //                                <img height='100' width='100' style='border 5px solid gray;' `enter code here`src='cid:prf' alt='' />
            $mail->MsgHTML($MsgBody);

            return $mail->Send();
        } catch (Exception enter code hereon $e)
        {
            echo $e;
        }
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    }

    ?>
-----------
OR
-----------
$SendFrom = "To: $msgTo\r\n";
$SendFrom .= "From: no-reply@email.com\r\n";
$SendFrom .= "Bcc: $bcc\r\n";
$SendFrom .= "X-Mailer: PHP".phpversion();
```

Comment: where did you pull this from and without any explanation? Kind of like pulling a rabbit out of a hat.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in a situation that my host doesn't so much open SMTP how can i use this code?