# Php variable not showing up in email

Tags: php, email

I have tried all that I could and finally thought of asking here :

I have a checkbox where multiple values can be checked, in my php I am trying to get those values in a variable like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {
      $proc = implode(",", (array)$procedure); 
}
echo $proc;
}
```

Issue 1. Its echoing the last value selected rather than the multiple selected.

In my html email template I have this :

```
<strong>Which procedure(s) are you inquiring about?</strong>
<p><?php echo $proc; ?></p>
```

Issue 2. Its not echoing any values here.

For the resolution of issue 1 , I tried the following code :

```
if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {
      echo $proc; 
   }

}
```

Prints out the values , without comma but still empty values in email.

Also since I am emailing these values echoing the result doesnt make sense , I was trying it for  testing purpose only.

Output of $proc as requested :

```
Vertical  Horizontal Flat
```

These are the values of the checkboxes , and the echo $proc is catching them correctly ..

Update: Mail function Code.

```
$user_email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
$filter_values = 'form, submit-btn';
$errors = '<p class="alert alert-success">Your message has been successfully sent !</p>';
$options = array(
'from_email'     =>  '',
'from_name'      =>  'form', // optional
'reply_to'       =>  'test@test.com', // optional
'adress'         =>  'my@gmail.com',
'subject'        =>  'contact',
'attachments'    =>  'img/wallacegromit.jpg', // optional
'filter_values' => 'form, submit-btn',
'html_template'  => '../forms/mailer/email-templates/contact-email.html', // optional
'css_template'   => '../forms/mailer/email-templates/contact-email.css', // optional
'sent_message'   => '<p class="alert alert-success">Your message has been successfully sent !</p>', // optional
'display_errors' => true // optional, default false
);
$sent_message = Form::sendAdvancedMail($options);

<strong>Which procedure(s) are you inquiring about?</strong>
 <p>{proc} </p>
```

And how in my case?

Update: This is the code which is replacing every posted values for the html email .

```
$filter = explode(",", $filter_values);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($filter); $i++) {
                $filter[$i] = trim(mb_strtolower($filter[$i]));
            }
            $replacements = array_merge($values, $custom_replacements);
            foreach ($replacements as $key => $value) {
                if (!in_array(mb_strtolower($key), $filter) && !is_array($value)) {
                    $html = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $replacements[$key], $html);

                }
            }
```

Comment: Okie, Why in the email its empty? any thought.

Comment: the email code is a seperate template file in a folder. All other values are visible except this one.

Comment: trying your suggestions.. now

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have changed the code to this - if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
    foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {
          $proc .= implode(",", (array)$procedure); 
          echo $proc;              
                       
    }
 
} Still empty values in email

Comment: got my money on the (unknown) form and the rest of the unshown PHP including `mail()`.

Comment: Please send the output of $proc. Are you using phpmailer ?

Comment: @Basti yes I am using PHPmailer .

Comment: if your (again unknown/unshown elements/form) input doesn't contain `type="checkbox" name="procedure[]"` then that could be the reason. If it is, then you should have posted your HTML from the get go. Those checkboxes are probably not being treated as an array.

Comment: @phpnewbie the mails function works as you said. In which PHPmailer  Attribut are you trying to put $proc?

Comment: ping me if I hit the nail right on the head. I am moving on... good luck

Comment: @Basti Didnt touch anything in the phpmailer , I have just used the variable straight into html as shown in the code above

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure I ll , Thanks for your help.. Still trying

Comment: @phpnewbie Is the html code a part of the php script or this html code in another html page?

Comment: @Basti its a seperate file /forms/mailer/email-templates/contact-email.html' This is where I am inserting.

Comment: @phpnewbie did you included your php script to your contact-email.html ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- You were right , I have found the code in my Form processor which replaces every value posted. I am updating the question , please take a look and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence 
    $proc = implode(",", (array)$procedure);

Looks like does not accumulate the value in each iteration.
So it could be:

```
  $proc = "";
  if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
        foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {
        //accumulate with '.=' operator
        $proc .= implode(",", (array)$procedure); 
  }
  echo $proc;
```

(Sorry I can't add comments yet, only responses)

Comment: [*You should have waited...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35994773/php-variable-not-showing-up-in-email#comment59642490_35994773) --- *"Still empty values in email – phpnewbie"*

Comment: I have changed the code adding that dot in the bigging , the values are echoing , But nothingin the html email , shows empty.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to parse the template email like is specified here? [php-html-email-using-html-template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739188/php-html-email-using-html-template)

Comment: @MikeBau if you can help me understand how I will use that with my code.

Answer (score 0):

`echo $proc` will output only the last element of array. The value of $proc will be replaced.

```
  $proc = "";
  if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
        foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {

        $proc = implode(",", (array)$procedure); 
  }
  echo $proc;
```

To solve this you have to use operator'.='

New code:

```
  $proc = "";
  if(!empty($_POST['procedure'])) {
        foreach($_POST['procedure'] as $procedure) {

        $proc .= implode(",", (array)$procedure); 
  }
  echo $proc;
```

---

To get the $proc in your php you should use placeholder. So change

```
<strong>Which procedure(s) are you inquiring about?</strong>
<p><?php echo $proc; ?></p>
```

to

```
<strong>Which procedure(s) are you inquiring about?</strong>
<p>{{proc}}</p>
```

In your PHP script use the following code

```
$gethtml = file_get_contents('../forms/mailer/email-templates/contact');
$gethtml = str_replace('{{proc}}', $proc, $gethtml);
```

//Send mail
use

```
'html_template'  => $gethtml,
```

or use the attribute 'body' of PHPmailer

```
body = $gethtml;
```

Comment: I am getting this warning Warning: file_get_contents($gethtml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.

Comment: since the contact-email.html is in some other directory other than main form. Directory structure is mentioned in my question.

Comment: file_get_contents('../forms/mailer/email-templates/contact');